# How to reset the default values in a graphical user interface

Tags: matlab, interface, reset

I'm creating a graphic interface (manually) and I would like to have a reset button which reset  the default values.

I already code this

```
H.but(3) = uicontrol('Units','normalized', ...

    'BackgroundColor',[1 0.7 1], ...
    'Callback','MyFunction(''Reset'');', ...
    'FontSize',12, ...
    'Position',[0.04 0.54 0.1 0.05 ], ...
    'String','Reset');

case 'Reset'
clear all % Is not working and I think that isn't that I expect
set(findobj(H.fig,'style','edit', '-or','style','text'),'string','') % H is a global variable. This trial don't give the default value, it just clear certain boxes
```

Comment: What do you expect the `case` statement to do there? `case` should only exist within a `switch` block, and even then you want to actually have the callback code in your defined `MyFunction` callback function.

Comment: yes I create my function, define some button and some plot with switch and at the end I would like to reset the interface

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose your issue with the code you have provided. If this is all of your code then it's more wrong than right. If this is a subset of your code then post the rest of the relevant code. Make the question clearer or expect it to go unanswered / get closed.

Comment: I agree with Wolfie, however just as a side-note: you should avoid using `clear all` in any GUI environment, because you will erase all function handles etc, i.e. your `set(findobj(...)` will not work, because `H` will not exist. Generally, you should be very, very careful in MATLAB with `clear all`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to create a specific `reset_gui` function for my GUIs that resets all the relevant control properties (like checkbox states, strings in editable text boxes, etc.) to appropriate default values, as well as setting all relevant variable values to their defaults, clearing plots, etc..

If you'd prefer a generic option for resetting all UI control properties to their initial state, here's an example of one possible solution:

```
function example_reset_gui

  % Initialize GUI:
  hFigure = figure();
  uicontrol('Style', 'edit', 'Position', [20 100 100 25]);
  uicontrol('Style', 'edit', 'Position', [20 65 100 25]);
  uicontrol('Style', 'push', 'Position', [20 20 60 30], ...
            'String', 'Reset', 'Callback', @reset_fcn);
  drawnow

  % Collect default states:
  [defaultState{1:3}] = get_default_state(hFigure);

  % Nested reset function:
  function reset_fcn(~, ~)
    set(defaultState{:});
  end

end

% Local function:
function [hArray, propArray, valueArray] = get_default_state(hFigure)
  hArray = findall(hFigure, 'Type', 'uicontrol');
  propArray = fieldnames(set(hArray(1)));
  valueArray = get(hArray, propArray);
end
```

This creates a figure with 2 editable text boxes and a reset button. You can type whatever you want into the text boxes, and when you push the reset button it will clear them (i.e. set them to the default empty string they first contained).

The [local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) `get_default_state` will find all the [`uicontrol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) objects in the figure, then get all of their [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)-able properties (i.e. all properties that are not read-only), then [get](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) all the initial values for those properties. The three outputs are stored in the 1-by-3 cell array `defaultState`, which is accessible by the [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) `reset_fcn`. When the reset button is pressed, all of the `set`-able UI control properties are set to the values they had when first created.

It should be noted that any changes made to the [`Position` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html#property_d119e1087833) (such as due to resizing of the figure) could be undone by this approach. Using [`'normalized'` units](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.uicontrol-properties.html#property_d119e1088003) would avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to start your GUI over from scratch the easiest way would be to just close it open it again.  You can do that from your button's callback.  Which I pointed at a new function `restartGUI`.  That could be a subfunction of your main gui or its own m-file, your choice.

Your question is pretty light on details so I can't help with some of the specifics but this should give you the general idea.

IF closing and opening isn't what your want then in the `restartGUI` function  you would have to just manually reset the state of each of your uicontrols, etc. (whatever else is in your GUI that we can't see).

```
H.but(3) = uicontrol('Units','normalized', ...
    'BackgroundColor',[1 0.7 1], ...
    'Callback',@restartGUI, ...
    'FontSize',12, ...
    'Position',[0.04 0.54 0.1 0.05 ], ...
    'String','Reset');

% <<<< THE rest of your code >>>

function restartGUI(hObject,varargin)
global H
close(H.fig)  %Assuming H.fig the main GUI window.
%Call the GUI again which will restart it.
yourGUIFunction
```

Edit: added the use of the global H to close.